# How can i intergrating a website with Optaplanner (html,javascript,php)?

Tags: java, servlets, wildfly, optaplanner

Im developing a scheduling system that the user must be able to go online login to the website and feed schedules in pdf that will be received by optaplanner which will schedule the resources and return a grid that the user will be able to interact with dynamically. My question is how can i integrate my website with planner.I will appreciate your insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous approaches on how to tackle this. Check out [the webexamples](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/6.3.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#getTheReleaseZipAndRunTheExamples) and [their source](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/tree/master/optaplanner-webexamples). One of the approaches for integrating OptaPlanner in a web-app could be:

- create a Java EE web app (for deploying on a application server, f.e. Wildfly, Websphere, ...) with OptaPlanner as a dependency (see [the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/6.3.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#integrationWithJBossModules) for more info)
- create a few Servlets that handle login, uploading the PDF schedules, storing them
- create an EJB to convert the PDFs into a into a OptaPlanner problem description you implement on the back end (see the [integration chapter in the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/6.3.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#integration) and how [our examples handle the problem](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/curriculumcourse/persistence/CurriculumCourseImporter.java)
- create another EJB to handle the actual solving (run the solver, wait for the results, notify someone)
- create a few Servlets to interact with the solution

Do note, this is just a general outline: there's a lot of things left out for brevity (security, persistence details, etc.). Also, there are currently efforts to build an [OptaPlanner execution server](http://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2015/10/01/SneakPeekAtOptaPlannerWorkbench.html), but it's definitely not production ready yet (as of March 2016).

Comment: thank you very much highly appreciated.will provide feedback on progress.